# Exit code of roslaunch shutdown on node death

Tags: ros, roslaunch, shutdown

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I kill the process tree of roslaunch I get an exit code of 0 indicating success, which is what I would expect.

However, when I run roslaunch and manually kill one of the nodes that have the `required=true` attribute in the launch file it causes roslaunch to shutdown. In this case roslaunch returns 0 as well although an error occurred. Is there a safe way to determine if the shutdown reason was "good"?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219115/exit-code-of-roslaunch-shutdown-on-node-death/) by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 152 on 2015-10-14

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/11064/list-of-possible-exit-codes-from-roslaunch/?answer=16317#post-id-16317):

> Btw, this behavior and the meaning of
> the numbers isn't specific to
> roslaunch; roslaunch is just reporting
> back the exit code that the process
> gave when it died.

So, if you have manually killed ROS-node with `SIGINT` (which corresponds to Ctrl-C), then most probably it was handled by roscpp signal handler that eventually made `ros::ok()` to return `false` and thus you program have terminated normally. (I assume you are handling messages with either `while(ros::ok()){ros::spinOnce();}` or just `ros::spin()`)

Thus, sending a different signal, e.g. `pkill -SIGTERM your_node`, should change the exit code.

EDIT

Sorry, I am wrong. It doesn't work as expected. It looks like a bug or just a missed feature in `roslaunch`.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2015-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on 2015-10-14**:
Thanks for your confirmation. I killed one required node (out of many) with `kill <pid>`. I am not sure how roslaunch forwards the kill message when itself is being killed (which would be the good case). But if only one required node is killed it should report an error instead.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2015-10-15**:
I would suggest to open an issue on GitHub [here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm), so to officially confirm the bug and/or make a feature request.

**Comment by [sd1074](https://answers.ros.org/users/2110/sd1074/) on 2016-10-28**:
I faced the same issue and I believe it is an important feature missing in roslaunch. I submitted a feature request/but report here: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/919